# time limited ios feature

Tags: ios, app-store

I would like to put a free version of my ios app on appstore. This is a data driven app that remembers events on certain past dates. Can I limit the time of past event to ,lets say, 2 weeks? And if the client want to see the events added more than two weeks ago, he has to upgrade to full (for a fee) ? Is this possible, or will the app be rejected by the apple review process?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you think it would be rejected?

Comment: I don't think this is a good mechanism. Though I don't think it'll be rejected for this reason.

Comment: What woul be a better mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably be able to get away with this. You'll likely want to use an In-App Purchase mechanism to unlock archived events as opposed to having separate free and paid versions of the apps on the app store.

Comment: The point is that the app will sell for a few bucks, ant the user will be able to use it indefinetly, but if he gets the lite version for free, data entered more than 2 weeks ago will not be available,but in that time he can test all features... He'll either buy it or give up entirelly... The buy is through inapp payment....any better ideas